# Algorithm to recursively flatten a set of arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, reduce

I just wrote this very minimalistic logging helper. - it filters messages based on their level, nothing more actually.

Since I want those levels to be inclusive, i need to compute a flat list of included levels in the current one. A recursive reduce combined with a lookup seemed to be reasonable choice.

The only problem is, i have sense about how to describe what this function does, in terms of a reusable function name which i can store somewhere between generic reducer helpers.

Is there a name for the algorithm performed by the recursive reduce?

```js
const logLevel = process.env.LOG_LEVEL;

const levels = {
    info: 'info',
    debug: 'debug',
    warning: 'warning',
    error: 'error'
}

const includes = {
    [levels.debug]: [levels.info],
    [levels.info]: [levels.warning],
    [levels.warning]: [levels.error]
}

const format = {
    simple: (strings, ...values) => strings.reduce ((l, r, i) => [l,JSON.stringify (vals[i]),r].join (''))
}

const uniqueRefSlow  = (ele, ind, arr) => !~arr.indexOf (ele, ind + 1);

const Combine = lists => function concatTreeRecursive (levels, level) {
    let more = lists[level]||[];
    if (more.length) return more.reduce (concatTreeRecursive, [level, ...levels])
   return [level, ...levels].filter (uniqueRefSlow);
};

const reduceRecursive = Combine (includes); 
const combineLevels = levels => levels.reduce (reduceRecursive);
// ^  How is this operation called?
console.log (`Logging on level ${logLevel}`);

const Log = (levels = [LEVELS.info], tag = format.simple) => (strings, ...values) => {
    let message = tag (strings, ...values);
    if (!!~combineLevels (levels).indexOf (logLevel)) {
        console.log (message);
    }
    return message;
}

const debug = Log ([levels.debug])
const info  = Log ([levels.info]);
const warning = Log ([levels.info]);

debug`debug - filtered`
info`info`
warning`warning - included`
```

```html
<script>const process = {env: {LOG_LEVEL: 'info'}}</script>
```

Comment: Are you just asking for a good name of a function?

Comment: @DennisVash Actually I'm looking for a name of the operation, like *flatten*, there are existing algorithm for just about everything, so there has to be one for this operation

Comment: try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Array.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), hope it helps.